# How to get a picture by it's id from a table and move it from one td to another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, getelementbyid

My question is, how can I move a picture from one td element to another one by it's id? For example when I have a table with 3 rows and each row has 3 td elements.I need to know this, because I want to get the id of td element in which the picture is. After it I want to remove the picture from there and insert it to the new td element. For example from "number**10**", with a function movePicture("left") the picture should be moved 1 td to the left. The options should be left,right,up,down or 0,1,2,3. Thanks.

```css
td{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody>
<tr>
    <td id="number00">00</td>
    <td id="number10">
        <img src="pic.png" id="picture">10
    </td>
    <td id="number20">20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="number01">01</td>
    <td id="number11">11</td>
    <td id="number21">21</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="number02">02</td>
    <td id="number12">12</td>
    <td id="number22">22</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Are you moving the picture around in response to a click?  How to know where the picture should be moved to?

Comment: it's written in the example, from "number10" to "number11"... no not a click, for example with a function movePicture(**11**); the function should get the picture by it's id and remove it from there... in this case it would be "number10" and then it should be moved to the td element with the id "number**11**".

Comment: So the function just needs to move a picture to the row directly under it in the same column?

Comment: In this case, yes. but the function should be also be able to do it for other "positions" inside the table. As I said a function like movePicture(column,row), should look at the table, where the picture is at the moment, remove it from there and insert it to the new position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picture has a unique id so finding the id of the TD that contains the picture is not necessary.  To move the picture from anywhere to number11:

```
document.getElementById('number11').appendChild(document.getElementById('picture'));
```

OK now it sounds like you need a function:

```
function movePicture(direction) {
  // get the id of the td that contains the picture
  var currentTD = document.getElementById('picture').parentNode.id;
  // extract the x and y values from the id
  var x = Number(currentTD.charAt(6));
  var y = Number(currentTD.charAt(7));

  // alter the x or y value depending on what kind of move was requested
  switch (direction) {
    case "up":
      if (y > 0) y--;
      break;
    case "down":
      if (y < 2) y++;
      break;
    case "left":
      if (x > 0) x--;
      break;
    case "right":
      if (x < 2) x++;
      break;
  }
  // move the picture to its new home
  document.getElementById('number' + x + y).appendChild(document.getElementById('picture'));  
}
```

examples:

```
movePicture('down');
movePicture('left');
movePicture('up');
movePicture('right');
```

Quick setTimeout example:

```
var moves = ['down','left','up','right'];  // repeat when done
var index = 0;
function doTimedMove() {
  if (index == moves.length) index = 0;
  movePicture(moves[index]);
  index++;
  setTimeout(doTimedMove, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I know, but for example when I want the picture to move 1 td to the right, then I need to get the id of the td which is "number10" and then change the substring of it "number" + colVar + "" + rowVar. And then increment the colVar. But therefor I need to know what the number was before...

Comment: That's why I asked how do you know where the picture is going.  Is the destination based on where the picture currently is?

Comment: okay my fault, then yes it is. I want the picture to be able to move from the current position 1 td left,right,up and down.

Comment: Does appendChild remove the child from its old parent too?

Comment: is there maybe a way to modify the function, that it moves the picture after 1 sec? so for example, when I call this 3 functions, that they are called 1 sec after the previous one has been executed?

movePicture('down');   //after 1 sec
movePicture('left');       //after 2 sec
movePicture('up');       //after 3 sec

Comment: Added a setTimeout example